# Alternative to id selectors using tooltip in material design lite

Tags: html, tooltip, material-design-lite

I am planning on using repeatedly a list of tooltips on the same page. Since the id selector is unique I would prefer to use an alternative selector like a class to apply **one** tooltip on **multiple** elements, instead of creating duplicate tooltips just so I can match the id.
Example:

```
<p><span class="desc-mdl">MDL</span> is a great tool allowing web 
developers focusing on the code rather than dealing with design. 
<span class="desc-mdl">MDL</span> applies 
<span class="desc-css">CSS</span> and JavaScript to 
<span class="desc-html">HTML</span> elements. But is still provides 
enough freedom for a personal touch for the web page.</p>

<div class="mdl-tooltip" for="desc-mdl">Material Design Light</div>
<div class="mdl-tooltip" for="desc-css">Cascading Style Sheets</div>
<div class="mdl-tooltip" for="desc-html">Hyper Text Markup Language</div>
```

I know that for is reserved for ids but there has to be an alternative we can use avoiding creating hundreds of duplicate tooltips.

Answer (score -1):

For each tooltip you have to give each `div` tags. You should give `id` to mention tooltip (I did not find any way without `id`). Here is your working codes: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/shmshd12/pen/remjWm)

```html
<p><span id="tt mdl 1">MDL</span> is a great tool allowing web developers focusing on the code rather than dealing with design.
  <span id="tt mdl 2">MDL</span> applies
  <span id="tt css">CSS</span> and JavaScript to
  <span id="tt html">HTML</span> elements. But is still provides enough freedom for a personal touch for the web page.</p>

<div class="mdl-tooltip" for="tt mdl 1">Material Design Light</div>
<div class="mdl-tooltip" for="tt mdl 2">Material Design Light</div>
<div class="mdl-tooltip" for="tt css">Cascading Style Sheets</div>
<div class="mdl-tooltip" for="tt html">Hyper Text Markup Language</div>
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but that was not what I was asking for. 
I'm well aware of this method. But this brings a lot of unnecessary tags which I try to avoid.